# Checkbox selection is lost when using ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to initialize(check) my checkbox once based on some value.Hence i am using ng-init but problem is when i load another template and come back to that previous template again i think ng-init gets call and i loose those new checkbox selection.

Code :

```
$scope.lst = [
{item:'banana', selected:true},
{item: 'apple', selected:false},
{item:'milk', selected:false},
{item: 'tomato', selected:false},
{item:'juice', selected:false}
]
});
<div ng-repeat="item in lst">
     <input ng-model="item.parentSelected" ng-init="item.parentSelected=item.selected" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

So by default i would like to display banana as selected but problem is when user select apple and milk and i load another template and user comes back to same page(again i load first template) so i guess ng-init gets call again and i loose my apple and milk selection.

when i remove ng-init then i have apple and milk selection.

**Update:** I guess the problem is with ng-init only as because ng-model is binded with parentSelected and for apple and milk i have `selected as false` so when i select apple and milk and i load another template and again i load previous template ng-init is making selection of only banana because of `ng init="item.parentSelected=item.selected"`

How to make default selection of apple and preserve other selection when my templates gets load??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets lost because when you open again that view, the controller gets init again, and the previous selection gets lost because the view is init again from zero.

Define a service where to store your selection, inject it in your controller and store inside the service the selected value. 
Then define a function inside your controller called from the `ng-init`. Inside this function check if a value has been stored: if so, assign the value to the stored one, otherwise pre select the first entry.

I hope it makes sense

Comment: No controller is not getting initialize again.I am loading html template based on button click using ng-include so only problem is when my html template is loaded ng-init is called again which is causing problem

Comment: The `ng-include` creates a child scope by default and when you navigate back, your `ng-init` gets triggered again, and the value gets selected back to the first entry. You should be able to test that doing this: `ng-init="console.log('init');"`. You will see that this log will be printed even when you come back to your view

Comment: Yeah so i was right but then how to achieve it what i am trying?

Comment: The block of code you attached above, is it all in your template included through `ng-include`?

Comment: No i have 1 main page from where i have 2 html templates gettting load.So the code i have provided in my question is from first html template

Comment: As I told you above, here the issue is related with scopes and the init of the scopes when getting back to the view. Just out of curiosity: reading your names, are you sure that here you meant: `ng-init="item.parentSelected=item.selected"` and not `ng-init="item.selected = item.parentSelected"`?